# PowerShell: Setting an environment variable for a single command only

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, variables, environment

On Linux, I can do:

```
$ FOO=BAR ./myscript
```

to call "myscript" with the environment variable FOO being set.

Is something similar possible in PowerShell, i.e. without having to first set the variable, call the command, and then unset the variable again?

To be more clear about my use case - I don't want to use this as part of a script. Rather, I have a third-party script whose behavior I can control using environment variables, but, in this case, not command line arguments. So being able to alternate between typing

```
$ OPTION=1 ./myscript
```

and

```
$ ./myscript
```

would just be very handy.

Comment: I guess my question would be why you would need to do this? I would think that there is a better solution.

Comment: That's not usually a helpful question, @EBGreen. The fact that the capability is there in UNIX shells suggests that there is a use for it. Off the top of my head: controlling the username and email address git uses for commits. There is no command-line option for those - you have to set them either in ~/.gitconfig, .git/config in each repository, or envars. Of those options, envars are clearly easier to set on-the-fly (and conveniently override the values in the files). So if I want to change my author name for one "git commit" in powershell, how to do it?

Comment: Completely agree that asking why this is needed is pointless. It is as common as borscht when executing at the command line on Linux and those of us forced now to suffer with powershell (a syntactic nightmare if ever one existed) constantly have to search for answers to obvious techniques. Most of the time, they don;t even exist in powershell unless you count writing long scripts to do trivial things. Count me deeply frustrated with that shell ...

Comment: This feature is [under discussion for PowerShell 6](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3316).

Comment: Thanks for the link, @FranklinYu, but at this point it would be a _hopefully in a not-too-distant future version after v7.0_.

Answer (score 150):

Generally, it would be better to pass info to the script via a parameter rather than a 
global (environment) variable.  But if that is what you need to do you can do it this way:

```
$env:FOO = 'BAR'; ./myscript
```

The environment variable $env:FOO can be deleted later like so:

```
Remove-Item Env:\FOO
```

Comment: Just a thought: Couldn't you just spawn a new PowerShell process, handing the scriptblock into it via the -Command parameter? That way you don't have to clean up the environment afterwards, since that will be contained in the child process. Although I am talking to a PowerShell MVP so this probably doesn't work :-)

Comment: Keith, we have a push-environmentblock and pop-environmentblock in Pscx for exactly this scenario ;-)

Comment: Johannes, that would work as well but somehow seems like cheating. :-)  The PSCX Push/Pop-EnvironmentBlock (the one *I* changed to make work this way) would work but it doesn't have the automatic cleanup support that a scriptblock has.

Comment: Don't you need to set `env:foo` back to its old value (perhaps unset) instead of removing it?

Comment: as @Joey mentioned, if you want to do env vars cleanly, you could: `& {$pre = $env:foo; $env:foo = 'bar'; ./myscript; if ($pre) {$env:foo = $pre} else {Remove-Item env:\foo}`...  some might say _unwieldy_, but will avoid side effects...

Comment: I assume windows has the behavior where argv arguments are cleartext in the process table for all users, contrast with environment variables that are only readable by the process owner (e.g. why passwords/secrets as configuration/environs are preferred to  arguments). Is that correct?

Comment: You can concatenate several Env Variables at once:
$env:FOO = 'BAR'; $env:FOO2 = 'BAR2' ./myscript
Good luck all (y)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it opens with an opinion which is based around not understanding the question. The reason for having this mechanism is precisely that environment variables (for child processes) are not, or at least do not need to be, global variables (for the parent shell).

Comment: This is a horrible answer that is completely besides the question. How did this get net over 100 upvotes?

Answer (score 48):

2 easy ways to do it in a single line:

```
$env:FOO='BAR'; .\myscript; $env:FOO=$null
$env:FOO='BAR'; .\myscript; Remove-Item Env:\FOO
```

Just summarized information from other answers (thank you folks) which don't contain pure one-liners for some reason.

Comment: Does not work - the variable is not removed.

Comment: The 2nd vay works for me, windows 11

Comment: use `$env:FOO=$null` instead of `$env:FOO=''`

Comment: "Because an environment variable can't be an empty string, setting one to $null or an empty string removes it." according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-variable-syntax

Comment: @Dois I fixed the answer, however, as James Skemp quoted, setting $env:FOO to an empty string produces the same effect of a variable deletion.

Answer (score 41):

Making a 'subshell' by invoking powershell with a script block allows you to scope the changes to the environment:

```
pwsh -Command { $env:MYVAR="myvalue"; .\path\to.exe }
```

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't pollute global environment, even briefly, besides the `Start-Job` answer which is hard to work with.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `powershell` instead of `pwsh`.

Comment: Is `pwsh` some sort of alias? The command is not known in a current PowerShell.

Comment: @Andreas, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) is th executable name of [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). In the built-in _Windows PowerShell_, use `powershell.exe`. (The two CLIs are largely identical in terms of parameters.) If you want to call the same executable that underlies the current session, use `& (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path { $env:MYVAR="myvalue"; .\path\to.exe }`. You pay a performance penalty  for launching another PowerShell instance.

Answer (score 30):

I got motivated enough about this problem that I went ahead and wrote a script for it: [with-env.ps1](https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/9282ea8b0e016960135d3c9ab88419e1)

Usage:

```
with-env.ps1 FOO=foo BAR=bar your command here

# Supports dot-env files as well
with-env.ps1 .\.env OTHER_ENV=env command here
```

On the other hand, if you install [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) you can use `env.exe` which might be a little more robust than the quick script I wrote above.

Usage:

```
env.exe FOO=foo BAR=bar your command here

# To use it with dot-env files
env.exe $(cat .env | grep.exe -v '^#') SOME_OTHER_ENV=val your command
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be Gow, but it works on git for windows too as it provides env.exe.

Answer (score 10):

To accomplish the equivalent of the Unix syntax, you not only have to set the environment variable, but you have to reset it to its former value after executing the command. I've accomplished this for common commands I use by adding functions similar to the following to my PowerShell profile.

```
function cmd_special()
{
  $orig_master = $env:app_master
  $env:app_master = 'http://host.example.com'
  mycmd $args
  $env:app_master = $orig_master
}
```

So `mycmd` is some executable that operates differently depending on the value of the environment variable `app_master`. By defining `cmd_special`, I can now execute `cmd_special` from the command line (including other parameters) with the `app_master` environment variable set... and it gets reset (or even unset) after execution of the command.

Presumably, you could also do this ad-hoc for a single invocation.

```
& { $orig_master = $env:appmaster; $env:app_master = 'http://host.example.com'; mycmd $args; $env:app_master = $orig_master }
```

It really should be easier than this, but apparently this isn't a use-case that's readily supported by PowerShell. Maybe a future version (or third-party function) will facilitate this use-case. It would be nice if PowerShell had a cmdlet that would do this, e.g.:

```
with-env app_master='http://host.example.com' mycmd
```

Perhaps a PowerShell guru can suggest how one might write such a cmdlet.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this by running the script as a [Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job):

```
Start-Job -InitializationScript { $env:FOO = 'BAR' } -FilePath .\myscript.ps1 |
    Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

You could also pass arguments to the script, using the `ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Job`:

```
$jobArgs = @{
    InitializationScript = { $env:FOO = 'BAR' } 
    FilePath             = '.\myscript.ps1'
    ArgumentList         = 'arg1', 'arg2' 
}
Start-Job @jobArgs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

**Advantages and disadvantages**

- You don't have to reset the environment variable after the script finishes (which would require `try` / `finally` to do it correctly even in the presence of exceptions).
- The environment variable will be really local to the launched script. It won't affect other, possibly launched in parallel, jobs.
- The script will run in its own, somewhat isolated environment. This means that the launched script can't set variables of the main script, it has to write to the [*success stream*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3) (implicitly or by calling another command that already writes to the success stream) to communicate back to the main script. This could be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on the use case.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with interactive commands, that require user's input?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that CMD is the native CLI on the Windows kernel (and is still the automation interface for lots of tools), you may be executing your PowerShell script with `powershell.exe` from the CMD prompt or an interface that accepts CMD console statements.

If you are using the `-File` parameter to pass your script to `powershell.exe`, no other PowerShell code can be used to set an environment variable for the script to access, so instead you can set your environment variables in the CMD environment before calling `powershell.exe`:

```
> set foo=bar && powershell.exe -File .\script.ps1
```

A single `&` will also work, but will allow the command to continue if the `set` failed for some reason. (Is this even possible? I have no idea.)

Also, it may be safer to wrap `"foo=bar"` in quotes so that nothing following gets passed to `set` as the variable contents.

Answer (score 0):

In my use case I needed to set an environment variable so I can use it within a Docker Compose script.  within my Powershell Script I define the variable use a semicolon then call docker-compose on same line

```
$env:PLATFORM="linux/x86_64" ; docker-compose up -d --build
```

within docker compose I can now just use my ${PLATFORM} variable.

which looks like this

```
...
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    platform: ${PLATFORM}
...
```

Answer (score -7):

You can scope variables to functions and scripts.

```
$script:foo = "foo"
$foo
$function:functionVariable = "v"
$functionVariable
```

New-Variable also has a -scope parameter if you want to be formal and declare your variable using new-variable.

Comment: Hmmm... Don't think this answer applies here. PowerShell variables aren't environment variables. Based on the question, the asker isn't using environment variables as scratch space (like one would in CMD [if that were the case, this answer would apply]), but needs to manipulate the environment before invoking an external command and then restore the environment afterward (or something to that effect).