# Is there a C# mstest equivalent of system property in Java?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, system, mstest

I would like to be able to pass a system argument - "host" to the MStest suite. To create automated jobs for continuous integration, I want to be able to specify the host as a parameter so the tests are run on that specific host. I couldn't find any such option with mstest. 
In Java, -Dhost="localhost" would work which can be specified as a parameter for the running VM. Is there a similar way in MStest for C#?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an equivalent to the Java system properties that you mention.  Here are a couple of ideas on how to approximate what you are looking for:

[1]

Visual Studio test support does include [Test Run Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182480(v=VS.90).aspx) (renamed [Test Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010).  This is a file that specifies many settings that control aspects of the test run.  For example, you can deploy additional files alongside your test, or run a "setup" batch script before your test run begins.

If you have a finite set of hosts, you could have a separate test run config/test settings for each host.  Each config/settings would deploy a file that contains the name of a different host.  You could then read in that file as part of your unit test setup, perhaps from your `[TestInitialize]` method.  A bit hokey, but maybe it would do what you want.

[2]

You could set a system environment variable (e.g., "`TESTHOST`") before running the test, and then read that environment variable from your tests.  You could wrap all of this up in a simple program or batch script that accepts an argument to set the environment variable, invoke mstest, and unset the environment variable afterwards.  For example, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420719/powershell-setting-an-environment-variable-for-a-single-command-only) may give you some ideas on how  you might do something like this using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an exact equivalent.  Instead, try leveraging .NET configuration files:

Add an application configuration file (App.config) to your MSTest project.  Add your "system" properties as keys in the appSettings section.  Reference these values in your tests using the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` collection.