# Call a BAT in an elevated window and changing ENV variables before

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, environment-variables, powershell-2.0

In a PowerShell script, I have to call a batch file in an elevated window. 
So I do

```
Start-Process my.bat -Verb runas
```

Now, `my.bat` expects to have some of the ENV variables I set on the original window.
However, since the elevated window is executed as admin, those variables I set as a regular user don't appear to be set on the admin window.

Is there a way to set ENV vars in an admin window prior to calling `my.bat`?

Comment: Is it required that you make it run as admin using powershell? You could also make the batch script elevate itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Setting an environment variable for a single command only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420719/powershell-setting-an-environment-variable-for-a-single-command-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want isn't possible. For security reasons elevated processes don't inherit the parent's environment. What you can do is create a wrapper script that you run elevated and have that script set the environment variables from parameters before running `my.bat`.

IIRC "runas" isn't enabled for PowerShell scripts by default, so the wrapper script would have to be a batch file:

```batch
@echo off

set "VARIABLE1=%1"
set "VARIABLE2=%2"

call "C:\path\to\my.bat"
```

Run it like this:

```psh
Start-Process .\wrapper.ps1 -ArgumentList 'foo', 'bar' -Verb runas
```