# Start-Process -WorkingDirectory as administrator does not set location

Tags: powershell

When I enter the command

```
Start-Process powershell -WorkingDirectory "D:\folder"
```

it opens new PowerShell window with `D:\folder` location set.

But when I enter the command

```
Start-Process powershell -WorkingDirectory "D:\folder" -Verb RunAs
```

it opens new PowerShell window with admin rights **but** with `C:\Windows\system32` location set.

How can I open new PowerShell window with admin rights and my own location determined?

Comment: just do a `cd d:\folder` as the first command?

Comment: Windows resets the working directory upon elevation for security reasons, otherwise something planted in the current directory might inadvertently be run with elevated privileges. As 4c74356b41 said, you need to change the working directory in your code. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34261567/1630171).

Comment: thank you, I wanted to run script via powershell with admin rights that moves files from `\currentdir` but it moved files from `\system32`, but I've just discovered that I can get current location with `$PSScriptRoot` in scripts and it works great now

Comment: Beware that `$PSScriptRoot` gives you the location of the script, which isn't necessarily identical with the working directory.

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same problem and solved it with this command:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -verb runAs -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command', 'cd D:\folder'
```

Once you run the above command, Windows will launch with admin authority and the specified directory.

Comment: Note: Since -file and -command can't be used simultaneously, if you need to start a powershell script in the new admin powershell, just append `; & 'PathToPS1File';` to the `cd ...` string, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655

Answer (score 4):

Here's another example which can be used for opening CMD from PowerShell as an administrator into the current folder:

`Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList ("/k cd {0}" -f (Get-Location).path) -Verb RunAs`
if used within a script you can use
`Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList ("/k cd {0}" -f $PSScriptRoot) -Verb RunAs`

If you want to open a new elevated PowerShell session from the current one which is not elevated you can use:
`Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ("-NoExit",("cd {0}" -f (Get-Location).path)) -Verb RunAs`
or 
`Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList ("-NoExit",("cd {0}" -f $PSScriptRoot)) -Verb RunAs`
when used inside scripts

Answer (score 2):

When using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with **`-Verb RunAs`, a `-WorkingDirectory` argument *is* honored *if* the target executable is a *.NET* executable**; examples:

- `pwsh.exe` (the [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI) *does* honor it.
- `cmd.exe` and, curiously, `powershell.exe` (the *Windows PowerShell* CLI) do *not*, and invariably use `C:\Windows\System32`.

  - The problem exists at the level of the .NET API that PowerShell uses behind the scenes (see [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)), as of this writing (.NET 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7).

Unless you know that you're invoking a .NET executable, a **workaround** that changes to the desired working folder *in the new process* is therefore required; to offer a **more robust alternative to [ふゆな's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55236108/45375)**:

```sh
$dir = $PWD.ProviderPath # use the current dir.

Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe @"
-noexit -c Set-Location -LiteralPath "$dir"
"@
```

- The embedded `"..."` quoting around `$dir` ensures that paths *with spaces* are also handled correctly. (To use the current directory without an intermediate variable, replace `"dir"` with `"$($PWD.ProviderPath)"`.

  - Using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) isn't strictly necessary, but simplifies the embedded quoting; with a regular [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), the embedded `"` must be escaped as `` `" `` (or `""`).
- Using `$PWD`'s `.ProviderPath` property ensures that a file-system-*native* path is used (based on drive letters also seen in `cmd.exe`, for instance), given that the calling session's current location may be based on a PowerShell-only drive  (see [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)) that the elevated process may not have defined (at all or not based on the same root location).

  - *Caveat*: If the native path is on a *mapped network drive*, this won't work, because elevated processes do *not* see the same drive mappings; in that event, pass the underlying *UNC* path.

**Workaround for launching a *GUI* application elevated from a given working directory**:

Since changing to the working directory must happen in the new, elevated process, a *helper shell process* is needed to perform this operation, which is best done via `cmd.exe` (for better performance):

```sh
$exeToLaunch = 'Notepad.exe' # may include arguments
$dir = $PWD.ProviderPath # use the current dir.

Start-Process -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden cmd.exe @"
/c cd "$dir" & $exeToLaunch
"@
```

Answer (score -3):

Once you run Powershell as administrator;

user the push-location command like so:

```
Push-Location -Path C:\
```

or put it into your script and run the script from the elevated Powershell prompt.

Comment: The point is to launch an elevated prompt, and have that elevated prompt start at the location of the prompt that launched it, without having to type that location in.

Answer (score -3):

I just ran your code example and it opened correctly for me at the `WorkingDirectory` location. Ensure the directory exists before you run the command. I tested against a drive on `C` and secondary drive as well and both worked.

Comment: With `-Verb RunAs`, `-WorkingDirectory` is only honored by _.NET_ executables, so it doesn't work for `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` (which seems to have a native wrapper); however, it does work for `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) CLI.