# Powershell script Set-MpPreference not working correctly

Tags: powershell, security, windows-defender

I've written a shell script that will exclude a folder during Microsoft Defender Antivirus scanning. I don't have a lot of experience with shell scripting, and this is what I come up with:

```
Set-MpPreference -ExclusionPath D:\vpostest
echo "Exclusion Success"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

The first line of the code is where I mention the exclusion, and the following is just some kind of prompt to notify the user that the exclusion is a success (it is still a work in progress).

Once I run the script, I receive an error:

```
Set-MpPreference : Operation failed with the following error: 0x%1!x!
At C:\Users\zainur.ariffin\Desktop\Powershell test\autoExclusion.ps1:1 char:1
+ Set-MpPreference -ExclusionPath D:\vpostest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_MpPreference:root\Microsoft\...FT_MpPreference) [Set-MpPreference], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0xc0000142,Set-MpPreference
```

If I'm not mistaken, I've read that the following error indicates that Microsoft Defender Antivirus was not enabled. I have already enabled this feature and restarted my computer, and even check with 'Get-MpComputerStatus'. However, the same error keeps appearing. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**This is for anyone who have the same problem as me**

So I found out that the reason why the script file doesn't run properly is because I didn't run powershell as administrator. But how to run the shell script file as administrator?

I have tried to create a shortcut from the script file, and try to enable 'run as administrator' from the properties, but the option is greyed out. Meaning I couldn't choose that option so I have to find another way.

So I come to a conclusion that I need to create a script file that will grant admin privileges to the script that I want. This is because it's not possible to grant administrative privileges to a script within the script itself. The following is the command I use to grant admin privileges:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $scriptFile
```

The "`$scriptFile`" need to be the script file that you intended to use. I hope this is useful for people who have the same problem as me.

Answer (score 2):

[You found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357983/45375):

- The **[`Set-MpPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/set-mppreference)** cmdlet from the [`ConfigDefender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/) module **must be run *with elevation* (as administrator)**, as all cmdlets from this module that *modify* settings must.
- It is unfortunate that the error message reported by these cmdlets is so obscure (as of v1.0 of the module); if the need to elevate were stated clearly, the solution would be obvious.

  - Feedback regarding the module can be provided to Microsoft [via the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).

---

###### Ways to ensure that your script runs with elevation:

- **Ad hoc**, assuming your script-file path is stored in `$scriptFile`:

  ```
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell "-NoExit -File `"$scriptFile`""
  ```

  - `-NoExit` keeps the elevated session open after your script exits, so you can examine its output.
  - Using the `-File` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter is preferable for invoking script files, and the embedded double-quoting (`` `"...`" ``) ensures that paths with spaces are handled correctly.
  - Note that the elevated session's working directory (location) will be `C:\Windows\System32` (if you used `pwsh`, the PowerShell (Core) CLI instead, the caller's working directory would be preserved); if that is a problem, either modify your script to change the location or use a `-Command` (`-c`) CLI call that changes the location before invoking your script - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399496/45375).
- **Using *self-elevation***, i.e. modifying your script so that it re-invokes itself with elevation on demand, by placing the following at the start of your script:

  ```
  if (-not (net session 2>$null)) { # Test if the session is elevated.
    Write-Warning "Re-invoking with elevation, of necessity in a new window..."
    exit (
      Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path "-NoExit -File `"$PSCommandPath`""
    ).ExitCode
  }

  # ... rest of your script, which now runs with elevation
  # If powershell.exe was called, the working dir will be C:\Windows\System32.
  # pwsh.exe preserves the caller's working dir.
  ```

  - Note: This **assumes that your script doesn't need to support *parameters***; **if it does, a *robust* solution requires a lot more effort**: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375).
  - The [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) contains the full path of the running script.
  - `(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path` is used in lieu of hard-coding `powershell` to ensure that you're using the same PowerShell executable that was used to launch the script; that is, if you launched from *Windows PowerShell*, it'll use [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), if you launched from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), it'll use [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).
- **Creating a shortcut file (`*.lnk`)** interactively:

  - Since `*.ps1` files are *not* directly executable from outside PowerShell, using the path of such a file *alone* as the shortcut target won't work: it'll be treated as a *document* to *open for editing* instead.

    - This is also the reason that the `Run as administrator` checkbox is disabled in the `Advanced...` (`Advanced Properties`) sub-dialog.
  - Therefore, you must call the script explicitly *via PowerShell's CLI*; specify the following target *in combination with* checking `Run as administrator`:

    ```
     powershell.exe -NoExit -File "C:\path\to\your\script.ps1"
    ```
  - Note that *programmatic* creation of a shortcut file, via the [`WScript.Shell` COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//xk6kst2k(v=vs.85)) is unfortunately *not* an option, because it doesn't expose a property to request running as administrator.