# It is necessary that PsExec does not close at the end of the PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, psexec

I wrote a PowerShell script to get a list of users in the groups of the local computer.
When executed, a CMD opens with the input of variable values.
After entering variables, PsExec opens in the second CMD window, and after executing the command, both windows close.

```
$computer=Read-Host "Computer"
$login=Read-Host "Login"
$password=Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$group=Read-Host "Group"

Start-Process psexec -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-i \\$computer -u $computer\$login -p $password -s net localgroup ""$group"""
```

I need CMD with PsExec not to close. So that I can see the list of users.
Adding "pause" at the end of the code does not allow you to close only the first CMD window.

The "-NoNewWindow" parameter should prevent the second window from opening. And together with "pouse" it would be a solution.
But "-NoNewWindow" doesn't work(

What other options are there?
Or how to make "-NoNewWindow" work?

Comment: Have you tried to use -Wait option for Start-Process: Wait for the specified process to complete before accepting more input.  This parameter suppresses the command prompt or retains the window until the process completes.

Comment: Yes, "-Wait" tried.
It doesn't help(

Answer (score 0):

- To make the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call synchronous, add `-Wait`
- `-Verb Runas`, i.e. requesting *elevation* (running with admin privileges) *invariably* runs the elevated process in a new window - that's why it cannot be combined with `-NoNewWindow`.
- Remove `-i` from your [psexec.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) call; using `-i` when targeting a remote machine causes the process to run in a window on the *remote* machine.
- In order to pause after execution of the `psexec` command, so you can examine its output (and potential error messages), call `psexec` *via `cmd.exe`*, which allows you to append a `pause` call.

Therefore, try the following (using a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to simplify quoting):

```bash
Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs cmd -ArgumentList @"
/c "psexec \\$computer -u $computer\$login -p $password -s net localgroup "$group" & pause"
"@
```

---

An **alternative** is to run your PowerShell script *itself* with elevation, in which case you don't need [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) at all and you can call `psexec` *directly*, given that child processes launched by elevated processes are elevated too.

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$computer=Read-Host "Computer"
$login=Read-Host "Login"
$password=Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$group=Read-Host "Group"

# Now that you know the script is running with elevation,
# you can invoke psexec directly.
# This is not only syntactically easier, but is synchronous by
# default and allows you to capture output, if needed.
psexec \\$computer -u $computer\$login -p $password -s net localgroup $group
```

- Note the `#requires -RunAsAdministrator` [Requires statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Requires), which makes PowerShell refuse to run the script unless the calling process (PowerShell session) is elevated.

  - A more convenient solution is to make your script *self-elevating*, i.e. to make it re-invoke itself with elevation on demand - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77360136/45375).

Comment: Alas, the window was closing anyway.
But thanks to your explanation, I figured out how to do what I need to do.
Instead of *-Verb Runas* I used *-NoNewWindow*.
When opening the script with administrator rights, since the second window does not open, they also apply to psexec. And *-Verb Runas* becomes unnecessary.
And by adding a *pause* at the end, I didn't let the cmd window close, and I see a list of the group's users.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @jbans. I realized that it's better to use `cmd /c` to invoke `psexec` itself instead of using it on `net localgroup` - that way, the window stays open even if the `psexec` call fails. However, running the PowerShell script itself with elevation is definitely an alternative, and in that case you don't `Start-Process` at all, which simplifies matters - please see my update, which also shows how to mark your script as requiring elevation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got.
Displays a list of users and does not close the window.

*You need to run with administrator rights, because `NoNewWindow` is used instead of `Verb Runas`.

```
$computer=Read-Host "Computer"
$login=Read-Host "Login"
$password=Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$group=Read-Host "Group"

Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow psexec -ArgumentList "\\$computer -u $computer\$login -p $password -s net localgroup ""$group"""
pause
```