# How can we trigger the PowerShell file with both another user and admin privileges

Tags: powershell, uac, elevated-privileges, start-process

I want to launch the file `c:\dfs-build.ps1` with the specific user and admin privileges for that I'm trying to use the below command but it's not working.

When I'm opening the powershell manually  and running the below commands then it's working and able to run the commands in the `c:\dfs-build.ps1` file with both svc and admin rights, but when I automate everything to trigger as soon as the server comes up then it's not working.

To suppress the yes or no pop-up while opening the PowerShell as Admin I have disabled the `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin` in Registry but still no luck. Can anyone help me that what am i doing wrong.

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "pwds" -AsPlainText -Force))
$args1 = "c:\dfs-build.ps1"
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Argumentlist '-file $args1' -verb RunAs"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your code is indeed correct in principle (though additional quoting would be needed if your script file path contained spaces).
- There are **only two basic ways to *avoid* an (invariably interactive-only) [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) confirmation prompt**:

  - [Disable UAC altogether](https://windowsreport.com/disable-uac-windows-11/), which is *strongly discouraged*.

    - A comparatively less insecure - but *still ill-advised* - alternative is to set the [`ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/341747f5-6b5d-4d30-85fc-fa1cc04038d4) registry value at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` to `0x0`: This still requires *requesting* elevation, but - assuming that the calling user is an administrator - *automatically grants it*.
  - **Launch your process from a process that *itself* has been elevated** (is running with administrative privileges), of necessity with the same user identity.

    - An indirect way to do this is via a *scheduled task* configured to run with elevation and allowed to be invoked *on demand*, but this too requires running in the context of an administrative user - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555081/45375).

Without either, your inner `Start-Process` call, with `-Verb RunAs`, *will* trigger a UAC confirmation prompt.

---

**General tips for starting an *elevated* process *as a different user*:**

You indeed **need to *nest* `Start-Process` calls** - the outer one to start a process with *as a different user* (`-Credential`) and the inner one to start on as that different user *with elevation* (with admin privileges, `-Verb RunAs`) - because you cannot do *both* in a *single* call.

There are **pitfalls**:

- If the target user identified by the credentials isn't permitted to access the caller's *working directory*, an error occurs (with *administrator* credentials, this is unlikely to occur, however).

  - The workaround is to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)'s `-WorkingDirectory` parameter to specify a directory that the target user *is* allowed to access; e.g., `C:\` is a safe bet.
  - However, (even with direct `-Verb RunAs` use) the ***elevated* [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) process will *not* preserve its caller's working directory** and **defaults to `C:\Windows\System32`** instead - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399496/45375) for background information.
- **Quoting gets tricky** with such nested calls; a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...><newline>"@` or `@'<newline>...><newline>'@`) helps a bit, because it obviates the need for escaping escaping embedded quote chars.
- The nesting of `powershell.exe` calls means that the outer process - whose sole purpose is to asynchronously launch the elevated process - is *transitory and short-lived*, which can be *visually disruptive* (a window pops up and closes shortly after).

  - Using **`-WindowStyle Hidden`** in the outer `Start-Process` call avoids this.

Therefore:

```bash
$cred = [pscredential]::new("domain\user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "pwds" -AsPlainText -Force))
$scriptFilePath = "c:\dfs-build.ps1"

Start-Process -Credential $cred -WindowStyle Hidden powershell.exe @"
  Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-File \"$scriptFilePath\"'
@"
```

Note the need to `\`-escape `"` chars. that are to be preserved as part of the command seen by `powershell.exe`'s (implied) `-Command` argument after initially parsing its command line - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375) for background information.