# To perform operations you must run an elevated Windows PowerShell console

Tags: powershell

Hi i try to run 2 scripts for a non admin user. I have 2 batch files that calls my powershell scripts. One script is okay i can run it, but the other not it says To perform operations you must run an elevated Windows PowerShell console. Can someone help me.

My batch script

```
@echo off
SET DIR=%~dp0% 
RunAs /Samir:DESKTOP-R9QTPMR\Administrator /savecred
PowerShell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""'}"
```

My powershell script

```
Try {


if(Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name PSWindowsUpdate)
{
    Write-Host WindowsUpdate module is geinstalleerd -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host
}
else
{
     Write-Host WindowsUpdate module wordt geinstalleerd -ForegroundColor Green
     Write-Host
     Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force
}



Write-Host Checken of er windowsupdates zijn. -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host
if(Get-WindowsUpdate)
{
    Write-Host Windowsupdates word nu geinstalleerd! -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host

    Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install
}
else
{
    Write-Host Geen updates beschikbaar! -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host

}
}
Catch {

    Write-Host "Volgende foutmelding: $_"
}

Write-Host
Write-Host Over 10 seconden wordt het scherm afgesloten
Sleep -Seconds 10
```

Comment: I don't think `/Samir` is a valid switch for `runas.exe`

Comment: Your `runas.exe` call is syntactically broken; in addition to what Mathias points out (you probably meant `/user:DESKTOP-R9QTPMR\Administrator`), it's missing a command to execute. Your `powershell.exe` call is missing `-Verb RunAs` from the nested `Start-Process` call, which is what is required to run a script _with elevation_. When run in the context of a non-admin user, you'll need an admin's credentials to achieve elevation.

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: Okay but how can I use my admin credentials in the script to achieve elevation @mklement0

Comment: By default you cannot avoid a UAC dialog, if that is what you're asking. The only workarounds are insecure and therefore highly discouraged - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77412370/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 Another question /Samir is my account so I can’t use that, do I need to write user do you mean.