# Pytest run a 'setup' method based on pytest command line argument

Tags: python, pytest

My issue is, how can I execute a setup method, that is based on a pytest argument when I run pytest?  Basically I want this 'setup method' to run first before running any tests.

For simplicity lets say I have a file 'text_something.py'

```
import somemodule

def test_some(usefakemodule):
   ...
```

the 'somemodule' is either installed in the environment or not.  If its installed already, then it will work no problem.  If not, I need to add the path of the fake module by running a method that basically does sys.path.append(XXX).

In short, I want to run 'pytest -v --usefakemodule' if I want to use the fake module dir, or just 'pytest -v' to just use that library installed locally (assuming its installed there).

I tried adding a fixture (scope=session) in conftest.py, but it doesnt seem to run/execute it first before it executes 'test_something.py', which will then state no module named 'somemodule'

I can run a regular method in conftest, but I dont know how it can depend on the pytest command line argument 'usefakemodule'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your conftest.py you use **pytest_addoption** combined with **pytest_cmdline_main**,
pleas refer to the documentation for details.

```
import pytest


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--usefakemodule", action="store_true", default=False, help="Use fake module "
    )

def pytest_cmdline_main(config):
    usefakemodule = config.getoption("--usefakemodule")
    print(usefakemodule)
    if usefakemodule:
        print("OK fake module ")
    else:
        print("no fakes")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether/how you can have pytest accept extra arguments, but here are a couple other ideas for accomplishing this:

1. Just try to import the real module, and update the load path if you get an ImportError:

```py
try:
  import somemodule
except ImportError:
  sys.path.append(XXX)
  import somemodule
```

2. Or, use an environment var, and run with `USE_FAKE_MODULE=true pytest -v`:

```py
import os
if os.environ.get('USE_FAKE_MODULE'):
  sys.path.append(XXX)
```

Comment: Yea I guess first example could work, but if I have to base on multiple parameter, get messy.  With second example, how come if i run that i get USE_FAKE_MODULE not recognized as a command.  I am running in windows, does that only work on linux environment?  I know you are just setting an environment variable

Comment: Yeah, the syntax for setting the env var would be different on windows (though the python code should be the same, I think). You could see https://superuser.com/questions/223104/setting-and-using-variable-within-same-command-line-in-windows-cmd-exe or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420719/powershell-setting-an-environment-variable-for-a-single-command-only