# How to set environment variables in Windows Command Prompt so they’re passed in `docker run -e FOO -e …` like with bash export

Tags: docker, powershell

Is there a Windows equivalent to bash's `export`? I want to set an environment variable so that it's available to subsequent commands. I *don't* want to `setx` a permanent env variable.

For example this works as expected with Docker for Windows in a Windows Terminal PowerShell Command Prompt. The `FOO` environment variable value is available in the container.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> docker run -e FOO=bar centos env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=05b90a09d7fd
FOO=bar
HOME=/root
```

But how do I set an env variable in Windows with the equivalent of bash export so that it’s available *without* setting the value directly on each docker run command?
You can see here that `set` does not pass the value of `FOO` to the container.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> set FOO=bar
PS C:\Users\Owner> docker run -e FOO centos env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=6642033b3753
HOME=/root
```

I know I can create an env file and pass that to `docker run` but I'm trying to avoid that.

PS: I asked this question here but didn't get an answer:
https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-command-prompt-so-theyre-passed-in-docker-run-e-foo-e/106776/4

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? `$env:FOO = 'BAR' ; docker run -it -e FOO alpine:3.9 /bin/sh`
Here, running `env` in the container showed that `FOO=BAR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422082/4676641), you can set a local environment variable for your shell with Powershell's `$env:VARIABLE_NAME`.

If I'm understanding your question correctly this should work for you if your objective is to just grab the variable name/value from the current terminal session.

```
PS C:\> $env:FOO = 'BAR'
PS C:\> docker run -it -e FOO alpine:3.9 /bin/sh
/ # env
HOSTNAME=e1ef1d7393b2
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
FOO=BAR
PWD=/
/ # exit
PS C:\>
```

An equivalent of `unset` would be one of the following (thanks to @mklement0 for the suggestion) :

```
Remove-Item env:\FOO

# suggested by mklement0
$env:FOO = $null
```

Comment: For me it returns `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Answer (score 0):

Create a Powershell script `docker_run.ps1`

And inside the script, you can define global variables and then use them in the docker run command written at the end of the script.

This way it becomes easy to re-use the command easy to edit as well for any quick changes.

The file would look as below:

```
$global:ENV1="VALUE1"
$global:ENV2="VALUE2"

docker run -e ENV1=$ENV1 -e ENV2=$ENV2 --name Container_Name Image_Name
```

And now just run this script inside the `CMD` as:

1. `powershell`
2. `powershell docker_run.ps1`