# error pops on run cmd: K6_PROMETHEUS_REMOTE_URL=http://172.21.2.29:9090/api/v1/write ./k6 run main_smoke_test.js -o output-prometheus-remote

Tags: prometheus, k6

I installed k6 v0.35.0, go 1.17.3, xk6@latest, Prometheus 2.32.0-beta.0, xk6-output-prometheus-remote@latest, and try to run k6 script, but I got below error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHPAy.png)

I want to know whether k6 open source can save test result in Prometheus?

Comment: Please, no pictures of code or terminal output in your question. Include it as code block. That allows others to copy&paste and try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a command with syntax used in Linux/POSIX shells in Microsoft's PowerShell. PowerShell uses different syntax to set environment variables for commands.

To set an environment variable in PowerShell, you have to [execute a separate command before running your actual command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422082/112968).

```
$env:K6_PROMETHEUS_REMOTE_URL = 'http://172.21.2.29:9090/api/v1/write'
./k6 run main_smoke_test.js -o output-prometheus-remote
```

Alternatively, you can install [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) to have a POSIX compatible shell available.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my problem has resolved. @knittl