# Why the terminal inside VS Code doesn't inherit the http_proxy environment variable?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I added the following line
*"http.proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:1230",*
in Code's settings.json.

After that I opened one terminal in Code(it's cmd in my case) and type:

`set htt`

and it shows:

`Environment variable htt not defined`

Tried to relaunch the Code, still not working.

---

```
System info here:)
I'm using the portable version of Code btw.

Version: 1.87.2
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

---

I googled the problem, and found the Microsoft's doc:

[A child process inherits the environment variables of its parent process by default.
However, CreateProcess function enables the parent process to specify a different block of environment variables. For more information, see Environment Variables.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/inheritance#inheriting-environment-variables)

So is this because that VS Code somehow calls `CreateProcess` when launching a terminal?

Comment: I've found a solution to it though. Just set the env first and start code from CLI:)

Comment: If you have managed to resolve this on your own, you can post it as an answer, and you can also accept it.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Thanks for reminding that! I didn't know I could do that lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to expect `http.proxy` to set `http_proxy`. At least- the documentation for that setting doesn't say that it will do that. It *does* say that if you don't set that setting, it will inherit from the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables (if they exist). It doesn't say anything about the other way around.

Try just starting the VS Code process gaving it an environment with `http_proxy` or `https_proxy`. You can set those variables at the system level, or just for that VS Code process (see [PowerShell: Setting an environment variable for a single command only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1420719/11107541) and similar questions).

If other other hand your issue is that you started a VS Code process and gave it an environment with `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` defined, and you want the integrated terminal to inherit that VS Code environment, then you should take a look at the `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` setting (which has no effect on Windows).